# Something wrong with code

Tags: javascript, download

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = image;
link.download = 'Download.png';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

When I use this script it returns me a download error

```
(File not found)
```

Why?

Comment: The [`.href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href) is expected to hold a string value. `image` is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

`link.href = image;`

to

`link.href = image.src;`